# heterogeneous queries require the ansi_nulls and ansi_warnings options to be set for the connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created one stored procedure and put below line of code right after BEGIN statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]
    param1,
    param2
AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

    ....

END
```

When I execute the stored procedure, I get this error:

> heterogeneous queries require the ansi_nulls and ansi_warnings options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.

So my question is, is it due to the SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF statement in my code? I have seen many procedures in my past with same statement, and they never seem to have any issues. Please advise.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_and_msbi/2015/03/18/error-heterogeneous-queries-require-the-ansi_nulls-and-ansi_warnings-options-to-be-set-for-the-connection/

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: it's sql stored procedure